# Can I order a finite collection of distinct finite sets in such a way $A_i\cup A_{i+1}\neq A_i$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

If I have a finite collection of $n$ distinct finite sets $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$, can I give it an order $A_1,A_2,A_3\dots,A_n$ in such a way that $A_i\cup A_{i+1}\neq A_i\ \forall i$? It seems to me clear, but I want to be sure of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to order the sets by cardinality so $|A_1| \le |A_2| \dots \le |A_n|$.

If $|A_i| < |A_{i+1}|$ then certainly $A_i \cup A_{i+1} \neq A_i$. 
Yet, also if $|A_i | = |A_{i+1}|$  we cannot have $A_i \cup A_{i+1} = A_i$ as this would imply $A_{i+1} \subset A_i$ and then $A_i = A_{i+1}$.